# ajax requests are Pending parallel request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

What im doing is when page is loading im calling two ajax request

```
fetch_list_big();
fetch_list_small();

function fetch_list_big(){
  $.post(...);
}
function fetch_list_small(){
  $.post(...);
}
```

As the name suggests request in `fetch_list_big()` takes more time to complete than `fetch_list_small`.
But since `fetch_list_big` is called first the `fetch_list_small` says pending till `fetch_list_big` returns 200.

**big.php**

```
require_once('files_same.php'); #starts session /connection / configurations etc

#Some heavy mysql stuff  #say 5 seconds

echo json(...)
```

**small.php**

```
require_once('files_same.php'); #starts session /connection / configurations etc

#Some light mysql stuff #say 1 seconds

echo json(...)
```

How can i call `fetch_list_small()` after `fetch_list_big()` in parallel way and not make it pending ?

### Pending Requests

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWqOD.png

The first request is huge and takes 5 second in server

The last 3 are small request and should be returned before first one but they are pending.

### After First request returns 200

https://i.stack.imgur.com/trTnm.png

After first request returns 200 . the last 3 requests are executed.

### Problem

I want all the requests to Run Parallel without locking in server (is some kind of session is getting locked ? )

Comment: Why do you think `fetch_list_small` is pending on `fetch_list_big` completion? They both should perform in **async** way unless you expilcitly tell jquery to do sync request

Comment: that's the reason i'm asking this question. Its async btw

Comment: you can wrap your small function into `setTimeout`

Comment: Then I don't understand what you asking. Both requests perform in parallel (async). What's the problem?

Comment: see i updated question with screenshots @hindmost

Comment: Obviously your problem is **server-specific** and has no relation to JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want all the requests to Run Parallel without locking in server (is some kind of session is getting locked ? )

Yes; PHP will block other scripts from accessing the session, as long as one script instance is using it. (At least for the default file-based session storage mechanism.)

You can avoid this by calling [session_write_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) as soon as your script(s) are done with what they need to do with the session.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a callback in your `fetch_list_big()`

```
function fetch_list_big(callback){

    $.post(url, function(data){

        if(callback){

            callback();

        }

    });

}

fetch_list_big(function(){

    fetch_list_small();

});
```

Comment: no i want to call at same time not after big is completed.